# Fedora cause SSD to heat up even though it is not mounted

Tags: fedora, ssd, laptop, temperature

I recently installed Fedora 26 on my laptop: Lenovo Legion Y520, in the HDD (the laptop has 256G ssd +1T hdd). When I use Fedora, the temperature of my SSD rise high(70c+, much higher than when using Windows 10) I can notice this by just touching the part of the laptop where it is installed(the ssd is in the corner, far away from other hot components). The SSD is not even mounted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because a drive is not mounted doesn't mean that the system ignores it. It's constantly polling hardware to see if devices are removed, added, etc. You don't technically ask a question, but I'm assuming it's 'why', and that is your answer -- the system still acknowledges a drive in the machine and wants to know what's there, and gets stats from it, and as I said before, polls it for changes often.

Comment: How can I make the system just ignore the drive?

Comment: Remove it. If you're not using it there's no reason for it to be in the system.

Comment: I use it for Windows 10.

Comment: Then you have to live with it. You might be able to blacklist the device in the system, but honestly I think it's more work than it's worth. As long as your system is cooling properly, there's no reason to think that it warming up is a bad thing.

Comment: @TimS.  Warming up indicates power usage, and thus battery drain, which would be undesirable on a laptop.

Comment: Naturally, but what is the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, an unused ssd should not be hot, nor even warm. Perhaps it is doing some background housekeeping, but I doubt that this would last for long.

You might try asking Linux to [remove](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/Power+Systems/page/SCSI+-+Hot+add,+remove,+rescan+of+SCSI+devices) the scsi device from its list.

Use `lsscsi` to find the *host:bus:target:lun* of the device, check it is not used with `lsof`, and then write the number 1 into the appropriate sysfs device. Eg:

```
$ lsscsi 
...
[4:0:0:0]    disk   ...  /dev/sdb 
$ sudo lsof /dev/sdb
$ sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /sys/bus/scsi/drivers/sd/4:0:0:0/delete'
```

Comment: Its an nvme drive. I attempted to disable it by rmmod nvme but its still getting hot

Comment: Perhaps you can find the device if you look down some other `/sys/bus/`, and see some similar tweakable pseudo-file, or `unbind` mechanism. You could also use `lspci` and `setpci` to control the actual pci bus registers to make it inaccessible on the bus. Did you check the logs for any messages?